# How to access json data in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I hope you can help me with this maybe simple question. So I'm trying to access the data of my the json file below:

```
[
  {
    "value": "12"
  },
  {
    "value": "94338"
  },
  {
    "value": "3.97"
  },
  {
    "value": "416"
  }
]
```

So I already have decoded the json file...

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("myjson.json");
$json_array = json_decode($json_string, true);
print_r($json_array);
?>
```

... which gives me the following result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [value] => 94338 ) [2] => Array ( [value] => 3.97 ) [3] => Array ( [value] => 416 ) [4] => Array ( [value] => 230 ) [5] => Array ( [value] => 0.05 ) [6] => Array ( [value] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [value] => 440 ) [8] => Array ( [value] => 230 ) [9] => Array ( [value] => 0.05 ) [10] => Array ( [value] => 0 ) [11] => Array ( [value] => 228 ) [12] => Array ( [value] => 12 ) )
```

So far so good :) But how can I now access the values of the json file? In other words how can I get the values - e.g. 12 or 94338.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: your JSON is invalid

Comment: What does this mean? I checked my json on https://jsonlint.com/ and it shows me "valid json"

Comment: You JSON is correct ignore Mehrdad.

Comment: it was invalid before it was edited, had a trailing comma

Comment: What have you tried so far? To me, this looks like a pretty common array, so why not use it like you would use **any other array** in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json_array[0], $json_array[1]
```

etc. will give you the specific value

```
$colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"];
```

$colors[0] will give you "Red"
$colors[1] will give you "Green"

if you have nested arrays like

```
$colors = [["Red"], ["Green", "Blue"]];


$colors[0] will give you ["Red"]
$colors[0][0] will give you "Red"
$colors[1] will give you ["Green", "Blue"]
$colors[1][0] will give you "Green"
```

Indexes can be string like in your example:

```
$colors = ["value" => ["Red"]];

$colors["value"] will give you ["Red"]
$colors["value"][0] will give you "Red"
```

If you want to loop over your array just use for or foreach loop

```
foreach ($json_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Have a nice day.

Comment: Teaching the basics. The PHP manual has a complete section on [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) OP could/should have read

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data you need with a basic [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
foreach ($json_array as $item) {
    // you have access to the value here
    echo $item['value'];
}
```